# Being identified as running Tor exit relay. Constant capchas, security checks

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, exit-relays, captcha

I recently realized that while using TOR (TOR bundle) that a site that wouldn't block out anyone because they use Tor, has Cloudflare service stating that they need to check the security of my browser which just sends me through endless loops of captchas and reloading over and over to verify I'm a human. Later on I was completely blocked out. Now I'm at the point where it says that I need to enable Javascript. This was happening while I had been using a VPN before connecting to TOR, an obfs4 bridge which probably isn't needed, setting security settings to safest, prioritize onion urls, HTTPS. I have never had a single issue with the site for some time now.

Tried to use Tails OS and the problem is still happening which is very frustrating. When checking out browserleaks website and while on tails it said that the IP that was being used had been identified as a Tor exit relay (something like "two of the same IPs have been identified as using being tor exit relays"). It's on a list of relays further on the page and the IP has the word reject next to it.

I've never volunteered to run an exit relay and am hoping to figure out a way to discontinue these captchas everywhere I go on TOR and allow access to sites.

Thanks for any advice as to how to get out of this annoying situation.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks for any advice as to how to get out of this.

If you want to use Tor, then there is no way around this. This is the limitation of using Tor. If a website does not want to allow Tor users, then it will block all Tor users and there's nothing you can do to get around that.

If the website is important to you then just use your normal connection + a VPN.  If they also block VPNs, then only use your normal internet connection or use the internet from your phone which will use a different IP than your computer.

More and more websites are doing this and while many of us think it is a stupid decision, they are trying to protect themselves from bots and other forms of attacks that come from Tor users. The best thing you can do is to contact the owners of the website and make your case as to why they should allow Tor users otherwise you just have to work around the limitations that they set for their own site.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not Tor-related at all! The truth is that these captchas e.t.c. are at the places where the AI is struck to classify you good enough to make an Ad list suitable for you OR/AND when you're threatening CDN censorship by running an IPFS node. This is based on 10+ years of my research and more than 500 cases when I helped innocent people to evade tracking and censorship. To destroy these detectors there's **only** one way - *just* to do these steps on *every* device you have:

- Install IPFS node **and** make it working via IPFS companion open-source add-on at least. Also there's an optional setting that you must enable - it's disabled by default - to cache **and** store **and** serve *just* the resources you have downloaded and/or used yourself
- Install and run **continiously** nodes for Tor, I2P - at least on a legacy server board or a basic modern one at least at your home, it's not mandatory to run it on mobile devices because of the battery and security. It's not a requirement to run an exit node for Tor! Just a middle one with ORPort and DirPort reachable
- Set up the WireGuard at your home and use it on all your mobile devices - with a static IP from your ISP. **Never ever use any DynDNS/DDNS service** Ever!
- Set up and run a mesh node for Yggdrasil and cjDNS, run them **continiously** at least at home at the board I've mentioned above
- Run a rTorrent client - just for DHT expansion - it is as light as a feather
- Install AdNauseam - the one that defeated Google's Ads AI - https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/google/google-bans-adnauseam-from-chrome-the-ad-blocker-that-clicks-on-all-ads/ and use it in every browser that is working with it

I'm running a project that saved people's lives - literally - and it's working! The longest ride and a most unexpectable one was when a man from Washington, USA - has actually came to visit me and say thanks personally to me in Moscow, Russia...

If you need deeper instructions on how to do the things I've mentioned upstrings - just drop me a line! But this issue, described in a question, is not related to Tor at all!